# C#'s IncrementArray and Array.Copy functions

Tags: c#, ruby

I am trying to port an app made in C# to Ruby and I am having trouble understanding a couple functions.

Here is the code.

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < EncryptedData.Length; pos += AesKey.Length)
{
    Array.Copy(incPKGFileKey, 0, PKGFileKeyConsec, pos, PKGFileKey.Length);

    IncrementArray(ref incPKGFileKey, PKGFileKey.Length - 1);
}

private Boolean IncrementArray(ref byte[] sourceArray, int position)
{
    if (sourceArray[position] == 0xFF)
    {
        if (position != 0)
        {
            if (IncrementArray(ref sourceArray, position - 1))
            {
                sourceArray[position] = 0x00;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else
    {
        sourceArray[position] += 0x01;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know that the length of the arrays and keys are 16.
I would appreciate if someone could explain how the Array.Copy and IncrementArray functions work.

Comment: I've added the IncrementArray function from the source code and I would appreciate some help explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Array.Copy copies data from one array to the other:

- incPKGFileKey is the source array
- 0 is the offset in the source array to start copying from
- PKGFileKeyConsec is the destionation array
- pos is the offset to in the destination array start copying to
- PKGFileKey.Length is the number of array items to copy

IncrementArray, to my knowledge, is not part of the .NET framework, and should be defined somewhere in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the quick detailed response. I was afraid that IncrementArray wasn't part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.Copy` is described, like any other .NET type or method, in MSDN library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5s0whfd.aspx

`IncrementArray` is obviously in your code (in the same class or the base class of this one), so you will have to read that code.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. You are both right, I have found the IncrementArray function in the source code. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: if you are in Visual Studio, position the caret at the function call and press F12 to navigate to its definition. You don't need to search. MonoDevelop offers similar functionality.